# Приложение meteor не запускается после попытки подключения GridFS store в проект

Tags: файлы, загрузка, meteor

необходимо загружать файлы с помощью GridFS.

как только в либах появляется:

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images");

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
   stores: [imageStore]
  });
```

проект проходит стадию Building for web и просто зависает, ошибок нет, все логи пустые

используются пакеты
cfs:gridfs
cfs:standard-packages

Comment: Этот пакет уже давно не поддерживается. Вполне вероятно что он уже не работает с новыми версиями метеора.